# Need Help With These 2 Problems find k*x)=f(og)

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Need someone to check If I'am write I think I have the write solution.

First question:

> Given: $g(x)=2x^2+5$ and $f(x) = x^2+4x$, find $k(x) = (f\circ g)(\sqrt3)$.

My answer:

> $k(x)=119+48\sqrt3$

Second question:

> domain for $k(x)$ if: $d(x)=\sqrt{x-2}$ and $g(x) = 3\sqrt{4-x}$ and $k(x) = (d\circ g)(x)$

My answer:

> domain = $\{x\mid 2\le x\le 4, x\in\Bbb R\}$

[ OP's original images, which I have translated into MathJax:
  [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xlTz6.png)
  [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ptiDv.png)
  [3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iYciA.png)
  [4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IgWXD.png) —Editor ]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have 
$$k(t)=(f\circ g)(t)=f(g(t)).$$
More informally, first do (apply)  $g$ to $t$, then do $f$ to the result.

Since $g(x)=2x^2+5$, we have $g(\sqrt{3})=11$. And now $f(11)=121+44$. So $k(\sqrt{3})=165$.

**Added:** Now that the second question has been LaTeX'ed (thank you, MJD), it can be attacked.

We want the domain of $d\circ g$. To evaluate $(d\circ g)(x)$, first we find $g(x)$, and then apply $d$ to the result. The function $g$ is only defined if $x\le 4$. And the function $d$ is only defined for inputs that are $\ge 2$.

Recall that what gets fed into the function $d$ is $g(x)$, that is, $3\sqrt{4-x}$.  So we need $x\le 4$ and $3\sqrt{4-x}\ge 2$.

For $x\le 4$, the condition $3\sqrt{4-x}\ge 2$ is equivalent to $9(4-x)\ge 4$. (We squared both sides.) This can be rearranged as $9x\le 32$, and then as $x\le \frac{32}{9}$.

So for the function $k(x)$ to be defined, we want $x\le 4$ and $x\le \frac{32}{9}$. The condition $x\le 4$ has become superfluous, since it is included in the condition $x\le \frac{32}{9}$. So $k(x)$ is defined for all real numbers $x$ such that $x\le \frac{32}{9}$.

**Remark:** Another version of the second question has $(dgg)(x)$, where presumably ordinary product is meant, since there is no little circle $\circ$.  If that is the intended function, then indeed the domain is the set of all $x$ such that $2\le x\le 4$.

Comment: im confused? what is the correct answer

Comment: The answer is $165$.

Comment: Thanks and the domain for the 1 one was I correct?

Comment: I have answered the domain question (could not read it before),